# TeamCity buildstep for generating WSDL file

Tags: web-services, wsdl, continuous-integration, teamcity

For a project we need to the wsdl files to be published in the artifacts folder.

For continuous integration we use TeamCity.
The project type is a Windows Communication Service Project.

Is it possible to have a buildstep that will generate the wsdl files from a webservice project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that just from the project.  Use a nant script or similar that can execute command line for you.  Have the script execute the tool against your project, you can use CmdHelper for example. http://www.stephan-brenner.com/?page_id=82

Comment: I tried the cmdhelper but I get the error: 
Could not load file or assembly 'assembly.dll' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Comment: even using svcutil to generate the wsdl gives the same error.

Comment: That is a different matter, you might have to update the runtime on the machine.  Possibly you have two or more runtimes, in that case make sure the newer one appears in the path first or refer to it explicitly.

Comment: could you perhaps give some further info about that? I already created  a seperate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495362/using-svcutil-to-generate-wsdl-gives-error